# How can I connect my firebase realtime database to datatables using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

I am trying to use the datatables plugin in my project, in which the database that I am using is the Firebase real-time database. The code below was the one that I have been working on, but it does not give me the results and functionality that I need for my project.

**Here are my JavaScript code for the datatables**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var dbref   = firebase.database().ref('passengers');
   dbref.on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
      var config = {
     apiKey: " ",
     authDomain: " ",
     databaseURL: " ",
     projectId: " ",
     storageBucket: " ",
     messagingSenderId: " ",
     appId: " ",
     measurementId: " "
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  
       var table =  $('#dataTable1').DataTable( {
           destroy: true,    
           "iDisplayLength": 5,
           "aLengthMenu": [
               [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
               [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]]
       });
       var dataSet = [snapshot.val().time, snapshot.val().temp, snapshot.val().date];
       table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
   });
  

});
```

**I have tried the code and here is the results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions but the best one I found is this :

```
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'age' },
            { data: 'email' }
        ]
    });

    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
    ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var data = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            data.push({
                "name": childData.name,
                "age": childData.age,
                "email": childData.email
            });
        });
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(data);
        table.draw();
    });
```